# What NPCs can you permanently kill in Bloodborne, and what are the implications?

Tags: bloodborne

I just begun playing Bloodborne, and I have already killed an NPC permanently (the red-cloaked dude in the chapel ward). I was going to ask what are the implications of such "accident", but I figured I will end up making the same question for several other NPCs.

Therefore, what I want to ask is:

**What NPCs can you permanently kill in Bloodborne, and what are the implications?**

Answer (score 4):

You do not have any direct consequences when killing an NPC besides that this killed NPCs will not help you in the combat anymore :P

When you kill an NPCs you also dont get a *punishment* of any kind. Other NPCs will think that they got killed by a enemy, even then when they have full health and you kill them directly in front of the other NPC.

The following reddit post contains a discussion on how to get the most out of NPCs. Warning! The Reddit post contains spoiler!
[Click here if you are aware of potential spoilers](https://www.reddit.com/311cxd)

[image]
<sub>Image 1 - A friendly NPC called Plain Doll. You can find her at Hunter's Dream</sub>

Comment: You should quote the post on your answer because links could die.

Comment: ... and this link has died.